# Where's the NSURLConnection protocol?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

The documentation of NSURLConnection says that there are delegate methods like

```
connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:
```

But the documentation doesn't mention which delegate protocol to implement. Well, I assume there just isn't any protocol for the delegate, so everything is just optional?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an [informal protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-TPXREF147) implemented in `NSURLConnection.h` as a category on NSObject:

```
@interface NSObject (NSURLConnectionDelegate)
```

That means any subclass of NSObject can be a delegate for NSURLConnection. Yes, all delegate methods are optional.

Comment: For anyone reading this answer in the future: [NSURLConnectionDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) is a formal protocol as of Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion).

Answer (score 0):

There is not one, and while there probably ought to be for completeness, it is unnecessary.  Objective-C works on a concept called [Duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) which basically means if there is a method on an object, even if it is not part of a protocol or header definition a message can still be sent to it.